# AngularJS - Bind object collection to HTML Table by range

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bind

So I have the following javascript collection of objects defined in a Controller called "MainController":

```
        $scope.records = [
            {
                id: 100,
                name: 'Item Shipping 100',
                minute: 7
            },
            {
                id: 101,
                name: 'Item Shipping 101',
                minute: 9
            },
            {
                id: 102,
                name: 'Item Shipping 102',
                minute: 15
            }
        ];
```

I want to bind this collection to an HTML table by a range of 10 minutes in each cell:

```
0 - 9
10 - 19
20 - 29
30 - 39
40 - 49
50 - 59
```

Each  cell represents a 10 minute range, in each cell I want to only show items in the records collection that fall in each range within the cell, this is the way I'm doing it right now, is there a Better way to do this? The reason I'm asking is that I have a lot more rows to add and I don't want to repeat this code many times, there might be a better way to bind this.

```
   <div ng-controller="MainController">

        <table class="table">

            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th>0 - 9</th>
                    <th>10 - 19</th>
                    <th>20 - 29</th>
                    <th>30 - 39</th>
                    <th>40 - 49</th>
                    <th>50 - 59</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>


                <tr class="even-row">


                    <td>
                        <div class="record" ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.minute >= 0 && item.minute <= 9">

                            <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>

                        </div>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <div class="record" ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.minute >= 10 && item.minute <= 19">

                            <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>

                        </div>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <div class="record" ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.minute >= 20 && item.minute <= 29">

                            <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>

                        </div>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <div class="record" ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.minute >= 30 && item.minute <= 39">

                            <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>

                        </div>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <div class="record" ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.minute >= 40 && item.minute <= 49">

                            <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>

                        </div>
                    </td>



                    <td>
                        <div class="record" ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.minute >= 50 && item.minute <= 59">

                            <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>

                        </div>
                    </td>


                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

 </div>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your ranges in the controller, something like:

```
$scope.ranges = [];
$scope.rangeStep = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < 60; i += step) {
  ranges.push([i, i + step - 1]);
}
```

Then in your HTML, write only one `th` such as:

```
<tr>
  <th ng-repeat="range in ranges">{{ range[0] }} - {{ range[1] }}</th>
</tr>
```

And only one `td` such as:

```
              <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="range in ranges">
                    <div class="record" ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.minute >= range[0] && item.minute <= range[1]">

                        <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                        <div>{{ item.name }}</div>

                    </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

This should do the trick, then if you want more columns or a different step, you just edit the `ranges` declaration in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add all ranges to an array in the controller and then loop over that in the view.

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("MainController", function($scope){
  
 $scope.minuteRanges = [
  {
    text: "0 - 9",
    min: 0,
    max: 9
  },
  {
    text: "10 - 19",
    min: 10,
    max: 19
  },
  {
    text: "20 - 29",
    min: 20,
    max: 29
  },
 {
    text: "30 - 39",
    min: 30,
    max: 39
  },
  {
    text: "40 - 49",
    min: 40,
    max: 49
  },
  {
    text: "50 - 59",
    min: 50,
    max: 59
  },
 ];
 $scope.records = [
            {
                id: 100,
                name: 'Item Shipping 100',
                minute: 7
            },
            {
                id: 101,
                name: 'Item Shipping 101',
                minute: 9
            },
            {
                id: 102,
                name: 'Item Shipping 102',
                minute: 15
            }
        ];
});
```

```html
<style>
table, tr, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-repeat="range in minuteRanges">{{range.text}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr class="even-row">
                    <td ng-repeat="range in minuteRanges">
                        <div class="record" ng-repeat="item in records" ng-if="item.minute >= range.min && item.minute <= range.max">
                            <div>{{ item.id }}</div>
                            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

 </div>
```